# wpf content print a textbox

Tags: wpf, printing, textbox

I am developing a text editor with WPF and have tried the following code to print the contents of a textbox:

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
if ((pd.ShowDialog() == true))
{
    RichTextBox richTB = new RichTextBox();
    richTB.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(TBXEditor.Text)));

    //use either one of the below      
    pd.PrintVisual(richTB as Visual, "printing as visual");
    pd.PrintDocument((((IDocumentPaginatorSource)richTB.Document).DocumentPaginator), "printing as paginator");
}
```

It does not work well. If I click the print menu ONCE, I get TWO prints and there is no left margin. The text at the beginning of the line is not printed completely

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Why does your code work not in a good way? What is the result and what do you expect?

Comment: If I click the print menu ONCE, I get TWO prints and there is no left margin. The text at the beginning of the line is not printed completely.

Comment: The comment `use either one of the below` means that you should use just one of the following two lines, but not both. That means, use `PrintVisual` or use `PrintDocument`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're getting two prints because you're calling two print methods (`pd.PrintVisual` and `pd.PrintDocument`). For margin, you need to set `Padding` for your `FlowDocument`. You can refer the below code, which works as you expected.

Also, you don't need to create `RichTextBox` and access the `FlowDocument` inside that. Instead you can create `FlowDocument` and work with that itself.

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    FlowDocument flowDocument = new FlowDocument();
    flowDocument.PagePadding = new Thickness(50);
    flowDocument.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(TBXEditor.Text)));

    printDialog.PrintDocument((((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowDocument).DocumentPaginator), "Using Paginator");
}
```